# update a entity with presave method to avoir a loop

Tags: database

In the hook_entity_update function

```
update_candidat_from_contrat_direct(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
```

I call another function in which :

- I create a new node

  ```
     $new_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create([
      'type' => 'candidat',
      'field_nom' => $nom,
    ]);
    $new_entity->save();
  ```
- I want to attach this $new_entity to the $entity

  ```
    $nid = $new_entity->id();
    $candidats_attaches[] = $nid;
    $entity->set('field_candidats', $candidats_attaches);
    $entity->save();
  ```

But because of the call to "save" function, this involve a new call to the "hook_entity_update", so another call to this sub-function, so a loop....

I understood that there is the "presave" function to avoid this behaviour, but I did not succeed to use it. Can I have some advices, please?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Both `hook_entity_presave()` and `hook_entity_update()` would be called when `$entity->save()` is called. `hook_entity_presave()` doesn't avoid the issue you have with your current code. Is `$entity` a node, or a different entity? In the case it's a node, is its content type different?

Comment: Also, the question seems to say that `update_candidat_from_contrat_direct(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)` is an implementation of `hook_entity_update()` but that's not true.

Comment: entity is a node.

Comment: "update_candidat_from_contrat_direct(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) " is called by "lamih_entity_update"

Comment: When entity is updated by the user, the aim is, within update_candidat... function, to, : (1) create an instance ot a content type, (3) fill its fields with values isued from entity form, (3) register id of this instance in a field of the entity, (4) update the entity in the database.

Comment: If I cannot use save or presave and if there are not any other solution, this leads me to asks the user to attach instance to the entity through the user interface. Not very good from my point of view.

Comment: You should update the question and show more of the code; just showing `update_candidat_from_contrat_direct(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)` isn't sufficient to answer the question. Without that, we cannot tell you if there is another way to achieve what you need. The question should also explain what you are trying to achieve, not only explain the code. Comments are ephemeral; every information that is useful to answer the question should go in the question.

Comment: ok. Nevertheless, I found an idea. If I succeed to implement it, I will put if here tomorrow.

Comment: I discovered that when hook_entity_update was fired for node "contrat_direct", node "candidat" was created thanks to data which were attached to "contrat_direct". So, to avoid the loop when I added the link to the "candidat" in "contrat direct", I erased these data from "contrat direct" in the right table just after the creation of the "candidat" instance.